# Customized List View in visual studio 2013 (visual basic)

Tags: vb.net, listview, visual-studio-2013, listviewitem

I'm new to the vb.net programming and I'm facing an annoying problem. I'm pretty sure that over the net you can find the solution, but I'm not able to probably because I don't even know the right words to be written.

My goal is to have a listview that have for each row 3 columns, the first and the last are just icons, the one in the middle contains two lines, the upper one is a label, the lower one is a progress bar.

I just did it for the mobile version of my app, and in android it is very easy, just a few XML to be done and some coding...is there something similar that can be done in vb.net?

thank you all for help
Cristiano

Comment: "... just a few XML to be done and some coding ..."  You can do the same thing in VB.Net, **if you use WPF** (not WinForms).

Comment: oh...thank you I'll check what is WPF and maybe I'll come back later.